# Control how angularjs converts date to json string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object containing a javacsript date. Something like this:

```
var obj = {
  startTime: new Date()
  ....
}
```

When Angularjs converts the object to JSON (for example, when sending it over $http), it converts the date to a string such as:

```
2015-12-20T15:35:15.853Z
```

I would like to have a timestamp instead of this string. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by `timestamp`? JSON is a string-based notation.  It must serialize it to a string in some format.  Do you want a different format? ISO 8601 is the default.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `getTime()` method to get a unix timestamp from a `Date` object:

```
var obj = {
    startTime: (new Date()).getTime()
}
```

Comment: changing the way the data is saved is not an option, i need to change they way the data is converted to JSON

Comment: so convert to timestamp just before sending it? obj.startTime.getTime()